# The intersection of a subgroup $H$ and one of its conjugates is always a subgroup of finite index in $H$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> $G$ is a group in which every subgroup has a finite number of conjugates. Let $H$ be a subgroup of $G$. Then I have to prove that the intersection of $H$ and one of its conjugates is always a subgroup of finite index in $H$.

I get no clue how to prove it. Plz help me. Thank you.

Comment: Is there any source of this problem ?

Comment: If this were true then I take $H=\{e\}$ its conjugate $\{e\}$.So $G$ is a finite group?

Comment: @Nimda I don't understand your comment. The problem would be trivial if $G$ was finite.

Comment: @Nimda: Index is finite in $H$ not in $G$. (you can not conclude $G$ is finite)

Comment: @DerekHolt For $H=\{e\}$ and it's intersection with $H$ then the statement says that the intersection $H \cap H = \{e\}$ is a group with finite index so $[G:\{e\}]<\infty$. Or am I wrong?

Comment: Yes you are wrong. It says $|H:\{e\}| < \infty$, not $|G:\{e\}|<\infty$.

Comment: @DerekHolt OK, but it should have been mentioned I think.

Comment: @Nimda: it is already mentioned. Last line "finite index in H"

Comment: @DerekHolt My mistake, sorry.

Comment: The assumption on $G$ is equivalent to its center having finite index. I think Neumann proved this, and showed the result you want as a consequence. I'm having a little trouble hunting this down for sure, though, due in part to paywalls.

Answer (score 1):

If $g \in G$ then $\langle g \rangle$ has finitely many conjugates in $G$, so $|G:N_G(\langle g \rangle)|$ is finite. If $\langle g \rangle$ has infinite order, then ${\rm Aut}(\langle g \rangle)$ has order $2$, whereas if it has finite order then ${\rm Aut}(\langle g \rangle)$ is clearly finite. So in any case ${\rm Aut}(G)$ is finite and, since $N_G(\langle g \rangle)/C_G(\langle g \rangle)$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of ${\rm Aut}(G)$, it is also finite. Hence $|G:C_G(g)|$ is finite.

Let $H \le G$, $g \in G$ and $I = H \cap H^g$. Clearly no element of $H \setminus I$ centralizes $g$, so the coset representatives of $H$ in $I$ lie in distinct cosets of $C_G(g)$, so $|H:I|$ is finite.

Note that this proof only uses the fact that all conjugacy classes of elements in $G$ are finite, which is weaker than the assumption that all conjugacy classes of subgroups are finite.

Comment: why the index of centraliser in normalizer of g less than equal 2?

Comment: @Via. I don't see why this would be true either, but it is certainly finite, which is enough.

Comment: Sorry, for some reason I was assuming that $g$ had infinite order. I have corrected it now.

Comment: I think N(<g>)/C(<g>) isomorphic to subgroup of Aut(<g>) which is finite.

Comment: @Derek Holt Can U explain a bit why the cosets of I in H are subsets of cosets of C(g)